# Test time based drools rules

Tags: testing, drools

Given the following drools rules:

```
import java.lang.Double;
import java.util.ArrayList;

declare SensorMessage
    @role(event)
    @timestamp(timestamp)
    @expires(10s)
end 

rule "temperature monitoring"
when
    $meta: SensorMetadata()
    $acc: Double () from accumulate(
        $message: SensorMessage() over window:time(1s),
        average ($message.getTemperature())
    )
then
    $meta.setTemperature($acc);
    update($meta);
end

rule "temperature activated"
when
    $meta: SensorMetadata(highTemperature == false, temperature >= $meta.targetTemperature)
    $lastMessage: SensorMessage($lastTimestamp: timestamp)
    not (SensorMessage(timestamp > $lastMessage.timestamp))
then
    $meta.setLastActivated($lastMessage.getTimestamp());
    $meta.setHighTemperature(true);
    update($meta);
    System.out.printf("temperature activated %.2f%n", $meta.getTemperature());
end
```

How would I be able to test whether the rule "temperature activated" has been fired `x` times exactly? The issue here is, that these rules are over a window, as well as that the message itself expires. So i would like to "simulate" time as well...

Is this possible?

Kind regards and happy holidays!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to test this is by using a Pseudo Clock: https://docs.drools.org/8.31.0.Final/drools-docs/docs-website/drools/rule-engine/index.html#rule-execution-modes-con_rule-engine

The idea is to have a clock that you can advance when you want it and how you want it:

```
KieSessionConfiguration config = KieServices.Factory.get().newKieSessionConfiguration();
config.setOption( ClockTypeOption.get("pseudo") );
KieSession session = kbase.newKieSession( conf, null );
SessionPseudoClock clock = session.getSessionClock();

session.insert( tick1 );
session.fireAllRules();

clock.advanceTime(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
session.insert( tick2 );
session.fireAllRules();
```

Note that the Kie Session you are using is configured with `clockType=pseudo`: https://docs.drools.org/8.31.0.Final/drools-docs/docs-website/drools/KIE/index.html

Hope it helps,

Comment: Dear Esteban, thank you!
How would I be able to additionally "test" whether a certain rule was fired at most `x` times?

E.g. the "temperature activated" rule only fires when the accumulated temperatures of the last 1 second exceed the target temperature, but how would i check that, with a certain set of test messages, this happens a certain amount of time?

Comment: One idea would be to use an `AgendaEventListener` in your tests that collects information about which rules were executed: https://docs.drools.org/8.31.0.Final/drools-docs/docs-website/drools/rule-engine/index.html#engine-event-listeners-con_rule-engine